# Can't evenly distribute spans inside div

Tags: css

I set `.inside` with `width:100%` and the `span` to have `width:25%` but the fourth span keeps getting pushed down.

http://jsfiddle.net/at8g6n0r/

Comment: first, put your code here not in fiddle. second your mark up is not perfect. you shouldn't call direct `div` inside a `ul`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.nav_list {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  display: block;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*as we will give its child element FLOAT property*/
}
.inside {
  width: 100%;
}
.inside > li {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  /* Inline-block has a browser issue, it leaves some margin*/
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.button-dropdown > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.nav .button-dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
.nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav li a span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #999;
}
.nav li a:hover,
.nav li a.dropdown-toggle.active {
  background-color: #289dcc;
  color: #fff;
}
.nav li a:hover span,
.nav li a.dropdown-toggle.active span {
  color: #fff;
}
.nav li .dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 3px;
  text-align: left;
}
.nav li .dropdown-menu.active {
  display: block;
}
.nav li .dropdown-menu a {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_list">
  <ul class="nav inside">
    <li class="button-dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
        Projects
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="button-dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
        Projects
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="button-dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
        → Resume (PDF)
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="button-dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
        About
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The easiest way is to add `float:left` to your child elements.
or You can also give the parent element- `font-size:0` and its child element the `font-size:needed font-size` property, this way you don't need to give `FLOAT:LEFT` property and fourth element will stay inline.

**Your HTML structure is bit wrong - following some bad practices, which won't get validated. for example: there shouldn't be any DIV inside UL as direct child.**

> Read more about inline-block issues here:
>   https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Ah I see. What should be a good way to go about doing this? I didn't know having a div inside a UL is a no-no.

Comment: check the markup I created in the answer - Its been changed there.

Answer (score 1):

didn't really added anything in your code just have removed the bad practices like div and span direct inside ul this looks good for now . if you want  it to be in certain way and not like this please let us know for now this will work.

```css
.nav_list {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  display: block;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.button-dropdown > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav .button-dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
.nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav li a span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #999;
}
.nav li a:hover,
.nav li a.dropdown-toggle.active {
  background-color: #289dcc;
  color: #fff;
}
.nav li a:hover span,
.nav li a.dropdown-toggle.active span {
  color: #fff;
}
.nav li .dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 3px;
  text-align: left;
}
.nav li .dropdown-menu.active {
  display: block;
}
.nav li .dropdown-menu a {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_list">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="button-dropdown"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
      Projects
    </a>

    </li>
    <li class="button-dropdown"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
      Projects
    </a>

    </li>
    <li class="button-dropdown"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
      → Resume (PDF)
    </a>

    </li>
    <li class="button-dropdown"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
      About
    </a>

    </li>
</div>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because inline-block keeps spaces between the elements if they are present.

you could:

1. open the next span right after the closing of the previous one
2. use display:block;float:left; and clear the float (e.g. by overflow:hidden on .inside)

Comment: why downvoted? It actually gives one more solution than the accepted one.